# Combining variance covariance matrices of mixed effects models with R

Tags: r, covariance, mixed-models, variance, r-mice

I have 10 different data sets in R and for the coefficients I have combined the estimates using Rubin's rules. How would I combine the variance covariance matrix? Should I find the mean for each value in my 10 matrices or be extracting the actual random effects estimates and be combining them and finding the overall variances? Likewise for the covariance values?

Comment: Great question, but one that belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). I *think* that a linear combination of positive-definite matrices should also be positive-definite (i.e., a weighted average of matrices should be sensible).  What do you mean by "actual random effects estimates" - the conditional modes/BLUPs?

Comment: In the output I have (I am fitting a Joint Model using JMBayes2 in R) the mcmc procedure output. Using the MCMC output that corresponds to the random effects you can find the corresponding variance.

I will put my question onto CrossValidated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the guts of [this package](https://teebusch.github.io/mifa/reference/mifa.html) give you the answer.  That is, provided that the authors of that package (and the referenced paper, Nassiri et al 2018) know what they're doing, [this code](https://github.com/Teebusch/mifa/blob/master/R/mifa.R#L96-L98) applies Rubin's rules at the level of the covariance matrix:

```r
# estimate covariance matrix of imputed values and combine estimates
cov_imps <- lapply(data_imps, stats::cov)
cov_comb <- Reduce("+", cov_imps) / length(cov_imps)
```

In other words, they're computing the mean of the full covariance matrix (this is equivalent to taking elementwise means). I would **not** compute the  covariance matrix of the combined BLUPs/conditional modes (for [reasons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68106/understanding-the-variance-of-random-effects-in-lmer-models)).

---

**Technical note**: Since [a linear combination of positive-definite matrices with positive coefficients is positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953141/is-a-convex-combination-of-positive-semi-definite-matrices-itself-positive-semi) (the linked answer refers to positive *semi*-definiteness, but I think the argument should extend to positive definiteness), the average of covariance matrices should also be a sensible covariance matrix.

---

Nassiri, V., Lovik, A., Molenberghs, G., & Verbeke, G. (2018).
On using multiple imputation for exploratory factor analysis of incomplete
data. Behavioral Research Methods 50, 501–517. doi: 10.3758/s13428-017-1013-4

Comment: I have had the time to properly go over this now and you have really helped. Your "(for reasons)" helped so much. Thank you so much for your time and help.